# Why do cosmetic surgeons recommend eating pineapple?

Tags: nutrition, surgery, plastic-surgery, bruising-bruise

*(I am not asking for advice on actually eating pineapple in this question. I am curious how this meme or trope has arisen.)*

I have had a number of surgeries in my time (I'm at the "use other side of page if necessary" stage of my life) and while many were impromptu, others were scheduled days or even weeks in advance. And none of the doctors involved, nor their staff, has ever given me any advice on specific foods to eat or avoid before and after the operation. But now I have a cosmetic procedure planned, and several people from the practice, plus a written brochure, have urged me to eat watermelon and pineapple for several days before and after. I was assured on the phone that they contain an enzyme that minimizes bruising.

I thought that to be unlikely, so I did a little searching. It was pretty easy to find sites making scientific-sounding claims, at least for pineapple (I included watermelon in the search, but the sites I found didn't mention it.)

> “Pineapple is the only food known to contain bromelain, an enzyme that helps your skin and tissues heal,” Zumpano shares. “Bromelain appears to produce substances that combat in pain and swelling.” Consuming bromelain from pineapple might also help your skin heal after surgery or injury. - https://health.clevelandclinic.org/benefits-of-pineapple/

> Pineapple contains bromelain, which is a powerful enzyme that has many surprising and helpful properties. Bromelain has a centuries-long history of being used to treat medical ailments, primarily throughout Central and South America. One of the main benefits of bromelain is that it speeds healing by reducing inflammation. Bromelain also minimizes the occurrence of bruising, which is particularly beneficial for recovery from plastic surgery.  - https://miaaesthetics.com/pineapple-juice-the-magic-surgery-recovery-drink/

> Pineapple contains bromelain, which is a powerful enzyme that has many surprising and helpful properties. Bromelain speeds healing by reducing inflammation. It minimizes the occurrence of bruising, which is particularly beneficial for recovery from cosmetic surgery. - https://www.thatsitfruit.com/blogs/default-blog/why-eating-pineapple-before-and-after-surgery-is-important

The last two are using the very same phrasing, which is probably not a coincidence. Over at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromelain), the story is a little different:

> While there have been studies into the medical use of bromelain, "the majority of [them] have methodological issues that make it difficult to draw definite conclusions", as none definitively established efficacy, recommended dosage, long term safety, or adverse interaction with other medications

I followed the link on that and it indicates there really haven't been any studies related to bruising and inflammation after surgery, what little studies there were concerned different things, though wisdom tooth surgery was one topic studied.

So I wonder why a cosmetic practice is so firmly recommending eating pineapple. (I'm also curious how watermelon got caught up in this, but set that aside for now.) Does it give patients a sense of control, that they can prepare for their surgery to go better? Is it trying to trigger a placebo effect? Is the slight luxury of fresh pineapple (some of these articles say canned or processed pineapple won't have the enzyme any more, while others encourage using bottled juice or canned segments) something that makes the whole "getting ready for surgery" a happier experience? Is this just some literal folklore that spread from practice to practice and website to website? Why don't people who remove gallbladders or clean up messed-up knees join in on these exhortations?

Comment: I'm guessing it'll be quite difficult for us to figure out why a specific person at the specific practice you describe makes this recommendation; you're probably better off asking them. It's not clear to me that "cosmetic surgeons" as a group make this recommendation rather than just *your* cosmetic surgeon. Still, the question of whether eating pineapple (or bromelain) has some positive impact during surgery seems like a good medical sciences question.

Comment: All my searches found sites associated with cosmetic surgery. My practice has already told me "Why" -- the surface reason that "it reduces bruising etc". Probably all the people who are telling me believe it. I'm interested in how this belief spread and why it seems to have only spread within a subset of the medical community

Comment: @KateGregory Probably because bruising is a significant concern for plastic surgeons but not so much for other types of surgeons.

Comment: @CareyGregory I find that surprising. Surely the person who fixed up my knee would want my post op discomfort minimized? Emergency appendectomy, I get it, but do most surgeons truly not care how people feel afterwards, as long as they're no longer dying or they can walk or whatever?

Comment: @KateGregory Sure they care about discomfort, but bruises don't usually cause pain; they're just ugly to look at. If there's pain, there's something more going on. I once had a cardiac catheterization procedure and the puncture site developed a large hematoma. Two days later my leg was black, blue, purple and everything in between from my groin to my knee. It looked like I'd been hit by a semi-truck, but it was utterly painless.\

Comment: @CareyGregory - What you had is not considered a bruise, it's discoloration caused by gravity pulling free RBCs down to the lowest point, and you're right, it looks like it should hurt, but it doesn't. We see that all the time with various injuries, e.g. a bad ankle sprain might show a line of discoloration along the edge of the foot a few days later, etc. Bruises hurt.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Then is there a proper term for it? I would assume what I described is more akin to what can develop following a surgical procedure.

Comment: @CareyGregory If there's a name for it, I never heard it. I've just seen it a lot, and patients even come to the ER a week after an injury wanting a distal area xrayed because "[we] must have missed something." I've even seen it several times on myself (especially after the leg injury). Perineal discoloration is a late (vs. acute) sign of coccygeal fracture, thanks to gravity. As to surgery, incisions bleed into the open, not trapped subdermally, and bleeding stops for all intents and purposes once sutured, so that doesn't happen with surgical procedures. Am I making any sense?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes, but I've seen the results of a couple of cosmetic surgeries, and in the first few days there was some minor, painless discoloration that most people would label "bruising." I'm left wondering what a surgeon would call it.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I guess when speaking to patients about it, e.g. after rhinoplasty, when bone is broken and subcutaneous bleeding does occur and the patient gets "raccoon eyes", they would call it "bruising" because it looks like a bruise. The actual name for it is periorbital ecchymosis. In charting, I've called it "ecchymotic discoloration 2° to pooling" to distinguish it from ecchymosis (a bruise) as a result of trauma. It's trauma related, but it's a distal discoloration.

Comment: @KateGregory - I commented, changed it to an answer, and didn't like the answer, so...I'm commenting. Docs aren't trained as scientists so most don't think like them. "Trends" are started for a number of reasons: tradition, gullibility (e.g. a respected doc or institution "said so"), outside influence (e.g. from a drug rep), misapplication (it works for this, therefore must work for that), whatever. Time to read and interpret the literature is a vanishingly scarce commodity in clinically practicing docs. That's why in the 90s, there was a strong push for...

Comment: ..."evidence based medicine", which resulted in the Cochrane Collaboration and Cochrane reviews. After some time searching and reading, it seems that only a relatively small percentage of bromelain (actually a complex of enzymes and glycoproteins) is absorbed intestinally, and the bromelain referred to in the literature is stem bromelain, where it is found in the highest concentrations. So eating the fruit is unlikely to make any difference as the amount of bromelain contained isn't sufficient to result in significant serum levels of the stuff.

Comment: As far as I can tell from my reading, the only proven beneficial aspect of bromelain is in wound care, where it helps speed debridement, e.g. it's used in burn units. All other claims are based on 'promising results which would benefit from further study' type findings, and that's for the drug, not what's absorbed from pineapple. So why are plastics people advocating it? I'd wager it's a combination of what @CareyGregory said (plastics folks are more concerned w/ the effects of localized edema on outcome), following the leader, and misapplication. Didn't post as an answer because it's opinion.

Comment: @anongoodnurse my first thought for bromelain was that it is unlikely to be absorbed; most will be broken down in the gut. Topical/subq I can see potentially useful in limited circumstances, but eating pineapple - no effect most likely.  [NIH centre for complementary and integrative health](https://www.nccih.nih.gov/health/bromelain) also says not enough information, implies direct application.

Comment: @bob1 - Agreed. There were rat studies with labeled bromelain that showed promise, but only one human study that I could find, n=18 healthy men given a high dose of drug and then serum was checked at 48 hours. There was bromelain id'd by immunoassay, and it was determined to be active still. But the conclusion was clear that only a small percentage of the drug was absorbed intact. I read and liked the NIH site you linked to yesterday; I like that there's information on alternative medicine. We're way behind in that field in the US.